# How to find recent questions or answers from users whose username contains a substring

Tags: support

So I found a very useful (to me) answer this morning on the n'th page of the recent activity page from a user and then an hour later I wanted to look at it again.  I can remember part of their username (but recall there being a couple of strange characters at the beginning and end).  I couldn't identify the question in my browsers history.  Is there any way I can query for recent activity from a user whose username contains a string?

Comment: Try filtering on https://stackoverflow.com/users/, it supports substring filtering.